# Flutter layout issue in ios devices, messed up layout in iOS devices

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm having a very weird problem with a layout. I've created a screen that is working absolutely fine in all android devices but when I run same code on iOS devices its it's messed up, am attaching screenshots of android and iOS. Here is the code for this screen. Same issue am facing in one more screen where I am having `column` in `card` widget. Please help me with this.

```
class _AddMoneyState extends State<AddMoney> {

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final theme = Theme.of(context);
final Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
return Scaffold(
  appBar: new AppBar(
    title: new Text('Add Money',
    style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
  ),
  body: new Container(
    child: new ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        new Container(
          width: double.infinity,

          height: 150.0,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child: new Card(
            elevation:5.0,

            child: new Center(
              child: new Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  new SizedBox(height: 30.0,),
                  new Text('ADD MONEY',
                    style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.blueGrey,
                        fontSize: 20.0),),

                  new Container(
                    width: 100.0,

                    child: new TextField(

                      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                          hintText: 'Enter amount'
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),

                  new SizedBox(height:10.0),
                  new Text('USD', style:
                    const TextStyle(color: Colors.blue,
                    fontSize: 20.0),),

                ],
              ),
            ),

          ),
        ),
        new SizedBox(height: 5.0,),
        new Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          height: 350.0,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child: new Card(
            elevation:5.0,
            child: new Center(
              child: new Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  new SizedBox(height: 10.0,),
                  new Text('CARD / BANK',
                  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),),

                  new Text('DETAILS',
                      style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0)),
                  new Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 60.0, right: 60.0),
                    child: new Form(
                      key: _formKey,
                      child: new Column(

                        children: <Widget>[
                          new Theme(
                            data: theme.copyWith(primaryColor: Colors.blue),
                            child: new TextFormField(
                                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                                style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                                decoration: new InputDecoration(
                                    labelText: 'CARD NUMBER',
                                    labelStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.grey,
                                    fontSize: 12.0)
                                ),
                                validator: (val) {
                                  return val.isEmpty
                                      ? "Please enter card number"
                                      : null;
                                },
                                onSaved: (String value) {
                                  this.card_number = value;
                                  // this._data.email = value;
                                }
                            ),
                          ),
                          new Theme(
                            data: theme.copyWith(primaryColor: Colors.blue),
                            child: new TextFormField(
                                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                                style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                                decoration: new InputDecoration(
                                    labelText: 'CVV/SECURITY CODE',
                                    labelStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.grey,
                                        fontSize: 12.0)
                                ),
                                validator: (val) {
                                  return val.isEmpty
                                      ? "Please enter card number"
                                      : null;
                                },
                                onSaved: (String value) {
                                  this.card_number = value;
                                  // this._data.email = value;
                                }
                            ),
                          ),
                          new Row(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              new Flexible(
                                child: new Theme(
                                  data: theme.copyWith(primaryColor: Colors.blue),
                                  child: new TextFormField(
                                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                                      style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                                      decoration: new InputDecoration(
                                          labelText: 'MONTH',
                                          labelStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.grey,
                                              fontSize: 12.0)
                                      ),
                                      validator: (val) {
                                        return val.isEmpty
                                            ? "Please enter month"
                                            : null;
                                      },
                                      onSaved: (String value) {
                                        this.card_number = value;
                                        // this._data.email = value;
                                      }
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              new SizedBox(width: 10.0,),
                              new Flexible(
                                child: new Theme(
                                  data: theme.copyWith(primaryColor: Colors.blue),
                                  child: new TextFormField(
                                      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                                      style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                                      decoration: new InputDecoration(
                                          labelText: 'YEAR',
                                          labelStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.grey,
                                              fontSize: 12.0)
                                      ),
                                      validator: (val) {
                                        return val.isEmpty
                                            ? "Please enter month"
                                            : null;
                                      },
                                      onSaved: (String value) {
                                        this.card_number = value;
                                        // this._data.email = value;
                                      }
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),



                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  new Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 40.0),
                    child: new Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        new Checkbox(value: isCheck, onChanged: (bool value) {
                          setState(() {
                            isCheck = value;
                          });
                        }),
                        new Text("SAVE THIS CARD FOR FASTER CHECKOUT",
                          style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 10.0),),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  new Container(
                    //width: size.width,
                    child: new RaisedButton(
                      child: new Text(
                        'ADD  MONEY',
                        style: new TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white
                        ),
                      ),
                      onPressed: (){
                        //sentMoney();
                        //print(Utils.token);
                      },
                      color: Colors.blueAccent,
                    ),
                    margin: new EdgeInsets.only(
                        top: 5.0
                    ),
                     ),
                   ],
                 ),
                ),


              ),
            ),

         ],
        ),
      ),

     );
   }
 }
```

Here is the logcat:

```
 flutter: A RenderFlex overflowed by 3.4028234663852886e+38 pixels on 
 the bottom.
 flutter:
 flutter: The overflowing RenderFlex has an orientation of 
 Axis.vertical.
 flutter: The edge of the RenderFlex that is overflowing has been marked in the rendering with a yellow and
 flutter: black striped pattern. This is usually caused by the contents being too big for the RenderFlex.
 flutter: Consider applying a flex factor (e.g. using an Expanded widget) to force the children of the
 flutter: RenderFlex to fit within the available space instead of being sized to their natural size.
 flutter: This is considered an error condition because it indicates that there is content that cannot be
 flutter: seen. If the content is legitimately bigger than the available space, consider clipping it with a
 flutter: ClipRect widget before putting it in the flex, or using a scrollable container rather than a Flex,
 flutter: like a ListView.
 flutter: The specific RenderFlex in question is:
 flutter:   RenderFlex#34c92 relayoutBoundary=up1 OVERFLOWING
 flutter:   creator: Column ← Center ← DefaultTextStyle ← AnimatedDefaultTextStyle ←
 flutter:   _InkFeatures-[GlobalKey#0628f ink renderer] ← NotificationListener<LayoutChangedNotification> ←
 flutter:   CustomPaint ← _ShapeBorderPaint ← PhysicalShape ← _MaterialInterior ← Material ← Padding ← ⋯
 flutter:   parentData: offset=Offset(118.0, 0.0) (can use size)
 flutter:   constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=347.0, 0.0<=h<=122.0)
 flutter:   size: Size(111.0, 122.0)
 flutter:   direction: vertical
 flutter:   mainAxisAlignment: center
 flutter:   mainAxisSize: max
 flutter:   crossAxisAlignment: center
 flutter:   verticalDirection: down
 flutter:
```

◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤
     flutter:

════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

**Here are the screenshots**

[image]
[image]

Comment: In my ios simulator everything is displayed correctly. Just had to remove the `height: 150.0,`in the first `Container` to avoid the pixels overflow.

Comment: which version of xcode are you using? I've update my xcode and using the latest one.

Comment: I think I also have the last one. Version 10.0 (10A255)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the issue, I was overriding fonts and the fonts that I was using were working perfectly in android but in iOS it was not working. I just commented this line in `main.dart` --

`//fontFamily: 'DINLightAlternate'`

And now its working fine in iOS devices too.

Comment: Man I was really confused this happened, this helped. wew.