# Flutter custom fonts doesnt work on ios simulator

Tags: flutter

I use 2 custom fonts on my flutter project, i have registered them on pubspec.yaml. Everything works perfectly on my android emulator and my real android device. But once i start running it on ios simulator, the whole layout went crazy.
I found the solution on here https://stackoverflow.com/a/52603332/12461018 and so i commented all of the custom fonts and the app works fine.

Now the question is how to use those custom fonts so it'll work on ios devices?

Comment: could you please check this solution https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/19452#issuecomment-419619132

Comment: @Sajjad all of the fonts i use have no spaces on their names